# FreePBX Asterisk play local audio file on demand

Tags: asterisk, voip

I have a working asterisk freepbn server running several conference call rooms. I would like to be able to play specific audio files from the server over the conference when selected from a simple interface (I'm thinking HTML) but have no idea where to start. 
The rough plan is that in time critical conferences the leader could select audio files that remind people how long is left "15mins remaining ". Later I play to script the playback but for now I am wondering if this is possible.

Thanks for any help,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Avatar-like systems are quite complex solutions.

There are no easy way do that. Very likly need expert/guru help.

You can start reading from this articles

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+channels

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out+deliver+message

Comment: Thanks for the links but they don't seem to give much of an answer. Could I not just place the channel in hold for the duration of the sound clip then unhold?

Comment: Yes,you can. But that will require very special patch for moh probably. Will be more complex. Sorry, no other way know except on links above. Sure you also can put both party to conference and put in conference any music(via patch or Spy), but that will be almost same.

Comment: Note, you can't change moh class while call bridged(conversation wiht other party). Same with conference, you can't change moh class when it running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will see what I can get working and report back.